# Integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^4}dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^4}dx$ via trig substitution. I decided to substitute $x = \sec\theta$ into the square root and $dx = \sec\theta \tan\theta\,d\theta$.

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\sec^2 \theta-1^2}}{\sec^4\theta} \,dx
= \int \frac{\sqrt{\tan^2\theta + 1 - 1}}{\sec^4\theta}\,dx 
= \int \frac{\tan\theta}{\sec^4\theta} \sec\theta \tan\theta\,d\theta = \int \dfrac{\tan^2\theta}{\sec^3\theta}\,d\theta$$

Here is where I am currently stuck. I attempted substitution with $u = \sec\theta, du = \sec x \tan x dx$ but that didn't seem to work out. I wasn't able to get an integration by parts strategy working either.

I think the answer lies in some sort of trigonometry regarding $\int \frac{\tan^2\theta}{\sec^3\theta}\,d\theta$ that I am overlooking to further simplify the problem, but no idea what it is

Comment: why did you multiply the numerator with sec$\theta$ tan$\theta$ without the denominator?

Comment: That was a substitution of $dx = \sec\theta tan\theta$. I will make an edit to make it more clear

Comment: Have you considered other substitutions? (not trig)

Comment: @GeorgSaliba no, the practice is specifically for trig substitution

Comment: @EvanKim oh okay, then the answer i was preparing defeats the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: I would still like to see it if you don't mind @GeorgSaliba because it will help me prepare for my exam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that$$\frac{\tan^2\theta}{\sec^3\theta}=\sin^2\theta\cos\theta.$$A primitive of this will be $\frac13\sin^3\theta$.

Comment: ah that was what I was looking for, thanks. Now with $\frac{1}{3} \sin^3\theta$, I know I need to replace $\theta$ with $x$, but I am stuck again. I thought maybe it was $\theta = \sin^{-1} (\frac{x}{1})$, but it does not even look close to the answer

Comment: Since $x=\sec\theta=\frac1{\cos\theta}$, $\theta=\arccos\left(\frac1x\right)$.

Comment: i don't follow the step from $\frac{1}{\cos\theta} = \arccos (\frac{1}{x})$. My brain keeps telling me that it shouldn't work because it is a $\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$ and not a $\cos\theta$

Comment: $$x=\frac1{\cos\theta}\iff\frac1x=\cos\theta\iff\theta=\arccos\left(\frac1x\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution (without trigonometry). Note that by integration by parts
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^4}dx&=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{3x^3}+\frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx\\
&=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{3x^3}+\frac{1}{6}\int \frac{D(1-1/x^2)}{\sqrt{1-1/x^2}}dx\\
&=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{3x^3}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{3x}+c=\frac{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}{3x^3}+c.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is yet another way of solving it:

Set $x^2-1=t^2x^2$ then $$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \qquad t=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$$ and $$dx=\frac {tdt}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}}$$

The integral becomes: $$I=\int x^{-4}txdx=\int tx^{-3}dx=\int t(1-t^2)^{3/2}\frac {tdt}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}}=\int t^2dt=\frac{t^3}{3}+c$$

then replace $t$...

PS: The substitution I used may seem arbitrary, but whenever you have an integrand of the form $x^m(a+bx^n)^{r/s}$, where $\frac{m+1}{n}+\frac rs \in \mathbb{Z}$, the substitution $a+bx^n=t^sx^n$ makes the integral more tractable.

Comment: What kind of substitution is this? I don't recognize it as the regular u-substitution that I usually use. I don't think I've come across this (learned it) yet

Comment: @EvanKim It's more of a trick (maybe in certain institutions in certain countries it is taught as part of the curriculum, but not necessarily everywhere). You can use it anytime the conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}}{x^{4}} d x \\\stackrel{y=\frac{1}{x}}{=}  &\int\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{y^{2}}-1}}{\frac{1}{y^{4}}}\left(-\frac{1}{y^{2}} d y\right)\\
=& -\int y \sqrt{1-y^{2}}d y \\
=&\frac{\left(1-y^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}+C
\\=&\frac{\left(x^{2}-1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3 x^{3}}+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a very good question and also it is a very easy question if and only if you understand the trick to solve this question. Let me tell you how to solve this without any trigonometric substitution and in a very easy way. First of all take $x^{2}$ common from the numerator. Now the expression will become $(x×\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}})/x^{4}$. Now cancel $x$ and $x^{4}$. So, the final expression will become $\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}}{x^{3}}$. Now I think you can solve it easily. Substitute $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ $=$ $u$. So, $\frac{-2}{x^{3}}dx$ $=$ $du$. So, $\frac{1}{x^{3}}dx$ $=$ $\frac{-1}{2}du$. Now try to solve it on your own. I have given you enough hints.